# Retrieve a Remote's Default Branch

Tags: c#, libgit2sharp

Within the scope of LibGit2Sharp, is there a way to retrieve which branch is the default branch for any given remote? Eg, what branch would be checked out if I were to do a fresh clone?

A `git.exe` equivalent might be:

```
git remote show REMOTE_REPO_NAME | grep 'HEAD branch' | cut -d' ' -f5
```

I can't seem to find an equivalent API call from within LibGit2Sharp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no way to get that information from libgit2sharp as it doesn't wrap the [`git_remote_default_branch`](https://libgit2.org/libgit2/#HEAD/group/remote/git_remote_default_branch) function from libgit2.

There is an open issue on GitHub ([#1796](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/1796)) about adding the `git_remote_default_branch` function to libgit2sharp. I tried searching the libgit2sharp repository for `git_remote_default_branch` but that issue is the only result.